# Merge sort - maximum comparisons

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I recently came across a problem where I was to find the maximum comparison operations when applying the merge sort algorithm on an 8 character long string. I tried implementing the 2r^r model however, the number of comparison operations used in a merge sort varies greatly with different input lists.

My question asked for the greatest number of comparison operations for one list. I applied the r2^r explicit definition which gave me 24. But the answer was 17. I can't find much information online or in the book about elementary algorithms and most solutions do not go into such details.

Does anyone know why this might be? I have seen some solutions where;

let 2^r = length of list, r2^r = greatest number of comparison operations.

```
2^r = 8
  r = log(8)/log(2)
  r = 3

Therefore, r2^r = 24
```

But that is not corroborated in my course.

any ideas?

Comment: What distinguishes this "cardinality" of comparison operations from the computational complexity of the merge sort, which in computer science is usually measured by the number of comparison operations performed? How is any computation complexity problem *not* a "discrete maths question on cardinality" according to your definition?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you showed, step by step, how you arrived at the answer $24$ so people can see how your methods reflect some kind of discrete maths cardinality approach instead of a computer science complexity approach. It would be better if you write the math in math notation; see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I distinguished it from a computer science problem as my understanding is that their implementations are different. In my experience, I use merge sort in Java or C++ to combine two lists and sort them in one function. You are right, the complexity of which would determine the worst-case/ greatest number of comparisons. However, the question specified one list of 8 elements which I am not used to.

Comment: Thanks, David I just added my method I used to find 24. I also removed the disclaimer.

Comment: Complexity theory in computer science involves no Java or C++. It's an abstract topic. But computer science also is a topic on this site, as you can see by searching the [computer-science] tag.

Comment: The added part is helpful (though it could use a little more care in presentation, for example it says `r^2` where I think you mean $2^r$). It's a version of the well-known $n \log(n)$ formula where $n$ is the number of items to sort and $r = \log (n).$

Comment: But I suspect there is still a misunderstanding. The answer $17$ may come from taking two sorted lists of $8$ items in each list (which could be characters in strings) and performing one pass of the merge sort algorithm on these two lists. So it would be important to examine exactly what your source is saying.

Comment: Also be aware that the $n\log(n)$ (or $r2^r$) formula is only meant to be asymptotically accurate, not a literal exact formula for every value of $r$, and furthermore formulas like this often assume you multiply the formula by some constant factor in order to get the (approximate) actual number of operations. For example, for $r=1$ you have $r2^r = 2$ but $r=1$ represents a list of $2$ items which takes only $1$ comparison to sort.

Comment: I am aware of complexity theory, I am a computer science 3rd year at ANU; It is related to Java and C++ and every coding language where there are inputs into functions. But thank you for taking the time to try and answer my question.

Comment: When I took a graduate course in complexity theory we never saw a line of Java, C++, or any other computer language. Granted, we also did not deal with anything as practical as merge sort. As a third-year, there's still a lot beyond your experience--and as someone who completed a PhD in the subject there's a lot beyond _my_ experience as well. Better not to rush to judgment.

Comment: $8!$ isn't very big.  You could check the answer with a program.

Comment: That is a truly incredible accolade - David K. I am currently pursuing a degree in Advanced Computing Majoring in Cybersecurity, with a Specialisation in Artificial Intelligence; with hopes of completing a PhD at some point. Thank you for your time, I look up to many academic scholars like yourself. I appreciate your time, I clearly have a lot to learn about Complexity !! Which is what I think I will do right now. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1...a_8$ be the input and let for simplicity let $ f_{i,j}\begin{cases} 
 1 & \text{if  } a_i\leq a_j \\  0 & \text{if  } a_i> a_j \end{cases}$, *i.e.* the $f_{i,j}$ are the comparison operations.

Let us go through the steps of Mergesort; there are 3 *levels* or phases corresponding to top-down recursive calls:

1. **Level 1** Compute $M(a_1,a_2) , ... ,M(a_7,a_8)$
2. **Level 2** Merge $(a_1,a_2)$ with $(a_3,a_4) $ and merge $(a_5,a_6)$ with $(a_7,a_8)$
3. **Level 3** Merge $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) $ with $ (a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8)$

Let us count the # of $f_{i,j}$ at each of the levels

1. **Level 1** has four comparisons $f_{1,2},...,f_{7,8}$
2. **Level 2** has at most 6 comparisons

   - Merge $(a_1,a_2)$ with $(a_3,a_4) $ takes at most 3 comparisons
   - Merge $(a_1,a_2)$ with $(a_3,a_4) $ takes at most 3 comaprisons
3. **Level 3** has at most 7 comparisons $f_{1,5},...,f_{4,8}$

   - After performing $f_{i,j}$ mergesort will then perform $f_{i,j+1}$ or $f_{i+1,j}$ until it hits $f_{4,8}$; the worst computation path could take 7 comparisons

Let us make an educated guess at the worst-case scenario, say $(7,4,3,6,5,2,1,8)$

1. **Level 1** will spit out $(4,7),(3,6),(2,5)$ and $(1,8)$ after 4 comparisons
2. **Level 2** will spit out $(3,4,6,7)$ and $(1,2,5,8)$ after 6 comparisons

   - $(3,4,6,7)$ will cause the comparisons $f_{1,3},f_{1,4},f_{2,4}$ to be computed
   - $(1,2,5,8)$ will cause the comparisons  $f_{5,7},f_{5,8},f_{6,8}$ to be computed
3. **Level 3** will spit out $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ after 7 comparisons

   - The following comparisons will be computed: $f_{1,5},f_{1,6},f_{1,7},f_{2,7},f_{3,7},f_{3,8},f_{4,8}$

***For a grand total of 17***

BTW the arguments and construction given can easily be generalized ... do you see the general pattern ... Good Luck with your mathematical voyages! Bon Voyage!

Comment: Okay yep, that's a great explanation. I see how they arrived at 17 now. I was quite confused. We have just covered proofs for strong induction, so I think I can induce an explicit formula from your solution that can solve for the greatest number of comparison operations. However, without skipping a beat we are now combining: Probability, propositional logic, matrices and algorithms - so RIP me. But knowing I can count on my math stack exchange community to help me out here and there gives me the confidence to continue strong on my mathematical voyage. Thank you Pedrpan !!

Comment: No problem, I am glad that I could be of use to you! Take care!